# Is it possible to model arrays as functions while preserving O(1) access times?

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, time-complexity, language-agnostic

It is quite easy to model linked-lists as functions, without any underlying collection data type, like so:

```lua
-- This is Lua code, but the specific language shouldn't matter
function createList(first, rest)
  return function(isFirst)
    if isFirst
    then
      return first
    else
      return rest
    end
  end
end

function nth(list, n)
  -- replace with n==0 for 0 indexing,
  if (n == 1)
  then
    return list(true)
  else
    return nth(list(false), n-1)
  end
end
```

However, this has the disadvantage when compared to arrays that index access has `O(n)` time complexity. I had been thinking that array literals would be easy to implement thusly:

```lua
-- {1, 2, 4, 8} ==
function someArray(n)
  if (n == 1)
    return 1
  elseif (n == 2)
    return 2
  elseif (n == 3)
    return 4
  elseif (n == 4)
    return 8
  end
end
```

But I realized that going through each `elseif` one at a time would still be access time `O(n)`. I considered a switch statement, as I was under the impression that C's switch statements jumped directly to the tag that matches the result of the condition, but this does not appear to be correct. It appears that with `n` branches, C's switch selects a branch in `O(n)` time. Is it possible to select a branch in constant time without using arrays? Is there some other technique for a constant time access to an array modelled as a function that I have missed?

Comment: This is a super-interesting question! My gut says that the performance of an array is a property of its physical representation in memory, not its API, whereas the beauty of Church Encoding (and other similar functional encodings) is that *there is no physical representation* in some sense; it is *only* an API. But I would love to see what comes out of this question.

Comment: yes, I suspect you're correct... But I hope not, I would like to find a function definition for array access

Comment: Are you talking only about index access or also about appending and writing? Because in that case, the answer is, you can't have a persistent immutable array with O(1) indexing, writing, and appending: if you keep your array as one chunk of memory, then you don't get structural sharing and have to copy the whole thing for writing, which makes it O(n). If you want some sort of structural sharing, then you need to traverse that structure, which makes pretty much everything O(log n). Note, however, that the constant factors can be held very low, so in real world usage, it is "almost O(1)".

Comment: For example, Clojure uses a 32-ary tree for its "arrays" (called *vectors*). Java only supports 32 bit array indices, .NET optionally also allows 64 bit. A Clojure vector with 4 billion entries is only less than 7 levels deep, so your performance is "O(7)". A vector with 2^64 entries is only less than 14 levels deep. A vector with 328,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 elements (the number of particles in the universe) is only 45 levels deep. So, for vectors the same size as supported by Java or .NET, the performance is …

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that Clojure uses tree for it's vectors! Very surprising, given that it's built for the JVM.

Comment: … very close, and even for absolutely ridiculous sizes, the performance is still good. Plus, you *never* have to defensively copy it when sharing between threads or functions, so *in practice*, it can actually turn out faster. All that's to say that maybe O(1) is not important, or as Rich Hickey, the designer of Clojure says "our arrays O(log_32 n), and in this case, the constant *does* matter". Or, as I like to say: "sometimes, *constant-ish* is constant enough."

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by the lack of need for defensive copying?

Comment: Immutable data structures are, well, immutable. You don't need to guard yourself against it being changed out from under you in a different thread / function, because *it cannot be changed, period*.

Comment: Gotcha! On another note, since I haven't figured out how to model a static array in O(1), wouldn't modelling an m-ary tree require O(m) at each level to access a particular element?

Comment: That depends on how you model it. Clojure uses Java arrays for the nodes, so indexing into the array is O(1) on each level. When you "modify" an element, you have to copy the path from the root up to that element, but that's only a maximum of log_32(n) arrays of 32 elements each you need to copy, so O(32 * log_32 n), which is of course just O(log_32 n). Anyway, m is constant, so even if you model it as a linked list, O(m) is still just O(1).